# How to do exception/error handling for a file in java for nullpointerexception and for reading permission

Tags: java, file-permissions

I have an absolute path. i want to handle the nullpointerexception when the file doesnt exist in the given path. if the file exists, then I want to check if that file is readable.

```
    Path path = Paths.get(testDocumentPath);
    if(Files.exists(path)) {
        if (Files.isReadable(path)) {
            //do something
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(message2);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(message1);
    }
```

when I execute the above code with a file that has no reading permissions, it still prints out message1. I also read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-directory-exists#nio) that is what happens with the exists() method above when the file doesnt have the right permissions. but it didnt provide a solution for me. i want my user to get two different warning messages for these two different situations. Any suggestions?

Comment: With "has no reading permission", what exactly do you mean? Does the user have any access to the file? If not, then probably already from the operating system level, there is no difference between a file that does not exist  and a file to which the user does not have any access to. And then, for Java it would be the same.

Comment: user has no access to the file. OK,didnt know that. then l have to rethink my approach. thank you!